# Can I define a trait whose implementations must be `!Send`?

Tags: multithreading, rust, traits

I'd like to define a trait which forces its implementors to under no circumstances be sent to, or shared between, threads. It should suffice to mark the trait as `!Send`, but Rust doesn't seem to let me.

Is it possible?

Example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=639a6e290a61436b0803999278993e62&version=nightly&mode=debug)):

```
#![feature(optin_builtin_traits)]

// This is a syntax error
//trait ThreadThing : !Send {}

// This doesn't work either
trait ThreadThing { }
impl !Send for ThreadThing {}
```

Comment: To what end would this be useful? Just don't send things between threads if you don't want them to be.

Comment: It would be nice to have it enforced by the compiler, no?

Comment: I honestly don't see how. If you try to send things that can't be sent, the compiler will already tell you. Substitute `Hash` or `PartialEq` for `Send` — what does enforcing that some type *not* implement a trait actually buy you?

Comment: The problem is, in one of the implementers the stuff that I don't want to be sent is behind an opaque pointer to some data structures that Rust has no knowledge of. Otherwise it would be automatic, like you said.

Comment: I guess this implementer is not `Send` by virtue of that raw pointer then...

Comment: Thinking of trait constraints as a subtraction of capabilities is bound to bring ugly looking edge cases. It might be best fo focus on what implementers can do, rather than what they cannot.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't make `!Send` a condition of `ThreadThing`. The compiler just doesn't support that kind of logic.

If it would be possible for someone *using* your crate to make a type that is implicitly `Send`, contains no unsafe code in its implementation anywhere, and *make it unsafe* just by implementing `ThreadThing` for it -- in that case, you would make `ThreadThing` an [`unsafe trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#implementing-an-unsafe-trait) to indicate that there is unsafe code somewhere that relies on an invariant that can't be described in the type system: the invariant "Things that are `Send` don't implement `ThreadThing`".

If, as is more likely, it's only unsafe to implement `Send` manually for a type that implements `ThreadThing` -- in that case, you don't need to do anything, because [manually implementing `Send` is unsafe already](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html). If an implementor of `ThreadThing` decides to manually implement `Send`, they take on the burden of guaranteeing not only their own invariants, but also `ThreadThing`'s.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: yes, you can, under some very specific conditions. Whether you should need to do this is another matter.

You can define a negative trait implementation for another trait if the trait you are negating is:

- an auto-trait.
- from the current crate.

So the following will work ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9e27115e9e6e0e00d562896242e5eab8&version=nightly&mode=debug)):

```
#![feature(optin_builtin_traits)]

auto trait Scary {}

trait ThreadThing { }
impl !Scary for ThreadThing {}
```

But it would not work if you were trying to do:

```
impl !Send for ThreadThing {}
```

Or if `Scary` was not an auto-trait.

Note however that, in general it should not be necessary to mark a trait `!Send` in this way. The concrete implementations of the trait will be marked `Send` or `!Send` by the Rust compiler based upon the contents of the implementing struct.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't do what you think. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5143ae8d2ec3fea8396ecac9f7f71c9d&version=nightly&mode=debug)) You unimplement `Scary` for the *type* `ThreadThing` (the type of trait objects of `ThreadThing`, as in `Box<ThreadThing>` and `&ThreadThing`). [In the future](https://github.com/Ixrec/rfcs/blob/dyn-trait-syntax/text/2113-dyn-trait-syntax.md), this will be written `impl !Scary for dyn ThreadThing` and there will be a lint to warn when you use "bare trait" syntax, because it probably doesn't do what you want.