# Can I have a generic function that accepts all types that do not implement a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I know that I can have functions accept only types that implement a given trait. For example, I can

```
fn f<T>()
where
    T: MyTrait,
{
    // Super useful stuff
}
```

What if I  wanted to implement a function that accepts anything that does **not** implement a given trait? For example, say that I have some computation that either:

- Requires some known, lengthy preprocessing, or
- Has a specific way of short-cutting through that preprocessing.

What I would like to do is something like:

```
fn preprocess<T>(computation: &mut T)
where
    T: !Shortcut,
{
    // Carry out the expensive precomputation.
}
```

I tried figuring out how to work around this problem, but I don't seem to be able to figure out any solution.

Comment: It looks like this is not available right now in Rust. There is [active discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1053) on the repo about it, but no commitment so far. The term you're looking for is "negative trait bounds".

Comment: Instead of a Shortcut trait, have a compilation interface which implements `preprocess` and the rest of the compilation process. Those which do not need preprocessing can implement an empty function. This is an OO approach rather than a procedural approach, you're asking the thing to do its own preprocessing.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot.

Instead, you can use the *unstable* specialization feature the other way, to opt-in to more efficient processing:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait Process {
    fn process(self);
}

trait Short {}

impl Short for i32 {}

impl<T> Process for T
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    default fn process(self) {
        println!("Processing {:?}", self)
    }
}

impl<T> Process for T
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug + Short,
{
    fn process(self) {
        println!("Shortcut {:?}", self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    42i32.process();
    vec![1, 2, 3].process();
}
```

```
Shortcut 42
Processing [1, 2, 3]
```

See also:

- [What are the possible operators for traits in a where clause in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46779310/155423)
- [Can I define a trait whose implementations must be `!Send`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50492087/155423)
- [What does the exclamation point mean in a trait implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30291217/155423)